# How can I find the *exact* reason for being awarded a badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

I recently got the "Unsung Hero" badge, which is nice.

I don't understand how: the description

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

doesn't seem to match what I've done. Looking at my recent reputation changes and inbox, I can't attribute it to anything.

So, given this or any other badge, how can I get a list of which questions/answers/comments/actions contributed to its being awarded?

Comment: BTW, for most of the badges (not `unsung hero`) linked with a question or answer they awarded for. Just click on them. [An example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/3/editor?userid=166026)

Comment: Go and have a look at [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397) (possible duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you *did* was get 13 accepted answers with score zero, vs 31 accepted answers that were upvoted; more than 10, and more than 25%. I guess a final 2 answers were accepted without upvotes (or maybe a previously accepted and upvoted answer was *unaccepted* making you hit the criteria).

So while your answers didn't perhaps get the upvotes they were due, they helped the OP. So... a badge, while *poor* compensation, is *some* compensation. You can see your answers on your profile page.

Comment: I got this badge *yesterday*. I've only had one zero-score accepted answer recently and that was three days ago. Before this I had 12 accepted answers with zero score, which is more than 25% of 43. Winding back a couple more weeks, I had 12 zero-accepts out of 42, no badge. Do these only get calculated every X weeks or something?

Comment: @spraff OK, I've dug into the code, and it looks like there's a date-restriction - it only considers answers added *10 days ago* (or earlier); presumably this is to stop a brand new answer (which has potential to be upvoted) from causing the badge to trigger. So to answer your question, on the 14th of September, you added an answer to question 7419211. The badge is related to multiple answers, however, hence why no single answer is cited in the badge award.

Comment: Actualy, that's what it says in the [full description of the badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258). I also used to be confused until I noticed that date restriction.

Answer (score 3):

More than 10 of your accepted answer had 0 votes and they represent 25% of your total accepted answers.